# Possible to do dynamic marshaling of structs in Go?

Tags: go

I have some redundant logic I'm extracting into a util to bind requests to structs and I was hoping I could do this dynamically somehow. What I want is to basically generically bind any request to the struct type I pass in. This would greatly reduce some code in my program.

I could have a `Task` struct or I could have an `Information` struct. All this information is coming into the server via JSON, but I want to be able to pass in the type name and have it auto-bind to reduce the code I'm writing.

#### Example Caller

```
func StoreTask(dbWrapper *database.DB) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        data := &utilities.DynamicStruct{entities.Task, r, rw}
        utilities.PersistRequest(data)
    }
}
```

Here's my small example:

```
type DynamicStruct struct {
    cType  interface{}
    writer http.ResponseWriter
    req    *http.Request
}

func PersistRequest(s *DynamicStruct, decoderOpts *DecoderMetadata) {
    r := s.req
    rw := s.writer

    // I want the struct to basically be able to take any type 
    data := s.cType

    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP %d - %s", 500, err.Error())
        http.Error(rw, err.Error(), 500)
    }

    // This is where the dynamic nature of the param would come into play that I'm looking for..
    newTask := new(data)

    decoder := utilities.GenerateDecoder(decoderOpts)

    // Using gorilla/schema here
    err = decoder.Decode(newTask, r.Form)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP %d - %s", 500, err.Error())
        http.Error(rw, err.Error(), 500)
    }

    rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(newTask)


}
```

Comment: How this can be done depends on what you're planning to do with data after `new(data)`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar newTask would be the struct (dynamically created) and then the req. information coming in would be bound to it using a decoder to populate the values.

Comment: I've added another snippet of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're marshaling, or decoding an unknown struct like this, there's nothing additional you need to do: just pass the interface value to the encoder, and it will encode the underlying value using reflection, or call the `MashalJSON` if it implements a custom marshaler.

```
dynamicStruct.cType=someStructValue
```

If you're unmarshaling, you can do the same by passing a pointer to a struct:

```
dynamicStruct.cType=&SomeStruct{}
```

Then you don't need to create a new instance of an unknown type, just pass the interface to unmarshal.

Comment: I'm getting a compilation failure. When I call decoder.Decode, it's expecting the struct to bind to, but I can't say newTask := new(data)

Comment: ahhhhh. I see what you're saying now. This is great, let me give it a shot

Comment: You don't need `new` at all. Just pass empty struct.